# How to see machines accessing bitbucket repo using ssh key?

Tags: ssh, bitbucket.org

I have a private bitbucket repository. I've added ssh access keys for accessing the repo. Its not at user level, rather at repository level. How can I see the list of IP address / users accessing the same repo ?

Comment: Do you mean a list of permitted users, or a list of users currently accessing it?

Comment: @harrymc list of users currently accessing it

Comment: What's the point of publishing a bounty and then abandoning your post?

Answer (score 0):

You say "currently accessing", which is not well-defined.
If you take it to mean users who have authenticated some short while ago,
then this is possible to do.

Some examples are given in the Atlassian article
[Query for inactive or idle users](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/query-for-inactive-or-idle-users-779171719.html).

This is an example query for MySQL:

```
SELECT 
    usr.user_name, 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(attr.attribute_value / 1000) AS last_authentication
FROM 
    cwd_user AS usr, 
    cwd_user_attribute AS attr 
WHERE 
    usr.id = attr.user_id 
    AND attr.attribute_name = 'lastAuthenticationTimestamp'
ORDER BY 
    2 ASC;
```

You could also install the free plugin
[Centralized license visibility](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1220745/centralized-license-visibility?hosting=server&tab=overview):

[image]